# Micro Cloud Foundry - can't create a new user

Tags: dns, vmware, cloud-foundry

I'm following the Micro cloud Foundry Quick-Start guide here:
http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20316811-micro-cloud-foundry-getting-started-guide

I'm on step 10: registering a new user and I'm not able to connect:

> $ vmc target api.lsmith.cloudfoundry.me
>  Host is not available or is
>   not valid: 'http://api.lsmith.cloudfoundry.me' 
> Would you like see the
>   response? [yN]: y 
> HTTP exception: Errno::ECONNREFUSED:Connection
>   refused - connect(2)

My VM is in NAT mode. The Current Configuration in my VM is listed as:

> Current Configuration: 
> Identity:   lsmith.cloudfoundry.me (ok) 
> IP
>   Address: 172.16.x.x (network up)

When I run the host command in my console I get:

> $ host api.lsmith.cloudfoundry.me
>  api.lsmith.cloudfoundry.me is an
>   alias for lsmith.cloudfoundry.me.
>  lsmith.cloudfoundry.me has address
>   127.0.0.1

I'm not able to reach the vmc target in my browswer but when I visit http://172.16.x.x/info I get:

> VCAP ROUTER: 404 - DESTINATION NOT FOUND

I think this is a DNS issue but have no idea what I need to do to fix it.  I tried changing the nameserver IP in my /etc/resolv.conf from 127.0.0.1 to 172.16.x.x but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by reconfiguring my domain (option 4 in the VM) using a newly generated domain token at https://micro.cloudfoundry.com/dns